# View Modifier Doesn't Update @State

Tags: swiftui, delegates, infinite-loop, viewmodifier, swiftui-state

Delegate Method Causes infinite Loop, and View Modifier Doesn't Update @State

I'm attempting to devise a way to measure the sizes of particular views in my computed `body` variable, and successfully created a means for doing so:

```
extension View { 
    @MainActor func viewSize() -> CGSize { 
        var viewSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) 
        let sizeRenderer = ImageRenderer(content: self) 

        sizeRenderer.render {  size, context in 
            viewSize.width = size.width 
            viewSize.height = size.height 
        } 
        
        return viewSize 
    } 
} 

protocol SizeMaster { 
    var bodyContentSizes: [CGSize] { get set } 
    func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: SizeMaster) 
} 

struct ViewSizeSender<Content:View>: View { 
    var sizeMaster: SizeMaster 
    var view: Content 

    var body: some View { 
        view 
            .onAppear { 
                sizeMaster.addViewSizeToCollection(view.viewSize()) 
            }
     } 

    init(sizeMaster: SizeMaster, view: () -> Content) { 
        self.sizeMaster = sizeMaster 
        self.view = view() 
    } 
} 

struct ContentView: View, SizeMaster {
    func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: CGSize) { 
        bodyContentSizes.append(size) 
    } 

    @State var bodyContentSizes = [CGSize]() 

    var body: some View { 
        ViewSizeSender(sizeMaster: self) { 
            Text("Size me up!") 
        } 
        .onAppear { 
            print(bodyContentSizes) 
        }
     } 
}
```

(I did notice that using this approach with multiple views causes the size for each view to be added to the array in reverse order — starting with the view at the bottom of the body block, and ending with the view at top of the body block. Wrapping all these views in something like a `Group` or `VStack`, and then putting an `.onAppear()` on that `Group` or `VStack` to print the contents of the `bodyContentSizes` array shows that the array is empty when that `Group` or `VStack` appears, so I can't make a `.reversed()` call on `bodyContentSizes` there. I can do that if I apply the `.onAppear()` to the first of these views that I wrap in the `ViewSizeSender`, though. I'm just a little nervous about doing that since I'm not sure that the body will always load its contents in that way. The most foolproof approach would probably be to assign each view an index number, and then have the `bodyContentSizes` array sorted by the views' index value every time a new view size is added. That's also a super wasteful approach...)

Returning back to the main question, I'd decided that having to wrap every view in this `ViewSizeSender` is a bit cumbersome, so I decided to try refactoring my approach so that my `ViewSizeSender` was a view modifier that I could apply directly to my view. I replaced `ViewSizeSender` with the following extension:

```
extension: View {
    @MainActor func sendSizeToSizeMaster(sizeMaster: SizeMaster) -> some View {
        sizeMaster.addViewSizeToCollection(self.viewSize()) return self
    }
}
```

and then refactored my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View, SizeMaster { 
    func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: CGSize) { 
        bodyContentSizes.append(size) 
    } 
    
    @State var bodyContentSizes = [CGSize]() 
    
    var body: some View { 
        Text("Size me up!") 
            .sendSizeToSizeMaster(sizeMaster: self) 
            .onAppear { 
                print(bodyContentSizes) 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

but now the `print` statement is showing that my `bodyContentSizes` is empty. I put print statements in my ContentView's `addViewSizeToCollection` method to try an diagnose the problem:

```
func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: CGSize) { 
    print("Size: \(size)") 
    bodyContentSizes.append(size) 
    print(bodyContentSizes) 
}
```

The first print statement shows that the view's size goes through as expected, but the second print shows that the `bodyContentSizes` array is empty. (Adding these print statements inside the view extension method gives the same results.)

I added an `.onChange(of:)` modifier in place of my view's `.onAppear()` to see whether the array was somehow getting updated after the UI had finished updating, but that block never ran. I also tried using an `ObservableObject` class to act as the `SizeMaster` in place of my `ContentView`:

```
@MainActor protocol SizeMaster { 
    var bodyContentSizes: [CGSize] { get set } 
    func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: SizeMaster) 
} 

@MainActor class ViewSizeRenderer: ObservableObject, SizeMaster { 
    @Published var bodyContentSizes = [CGSize]() 
    func addViewSizeToCollection(_ size: CGSize) {
        print(size)
        bodyContentSizes.append(size) 
        print(bodyContentSizes)
    } 
} 

struct ContentView: View { 
    @StateObject var renderer = ViewSizeRenderer() 

    var body: some View { 
        Text("Size me up!") 
            .sendSizeToSizeMaster(sizeMaster: self) 
            .onAppear { 
                print(bodyContentSizes) 
            } 
    } 
}
```

and was surprised to discover that I started having an infinite print loop where the printed array generated by `print(bodyContentSizes)` began to grow endlessly larger. (This happens regardless of whether or not my `renderer` is an `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`, or remove the `@MainActor` from the protocol and my class.)

Does anyone have any guesses as to what's going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.